Pandas 3.0 Copy-on-Write changes, how to best assign loc and iloc selection
I am preparing code for pandas3.0 and I noticed that the original syntax df['b'].iloc[0] causes a lot of future warnings.
Is there an alternative, more elegant way to express this instead of using df.loc[df.index[0], 'b'] = 9. It seems much less elegant.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[2, 3, 4]))

df['b'].iloc[0] = 9
df.loc[df.index[0], 'b'] = 9


Take a look at iat
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[2, 3, 4]))

df['b'].iat[0] = 9

Note that iat is meant to only set or get a single value, while iloc can access several values at the same time.

Thank you. Surprised to see no warning here. Do you know why the chained assignment error is not raised here?

In your case, df['b'] creates an intermediate Series, and then iloc is called on that Series. This chaining is what triggers the warning. iat directly accesses the element in the original DataFrame without creating any intermediate objects, avoiding the warning.

Check out this documentation on Copy-on-Write https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/copy_on_write.html#chained-assignment

brief follow-up, df.loc[df.index[:1], 'b'] = 9 would not be possible obviously with iat, is there a more elegant solution?
